# PHP Email script to send emails with attachment not sending video files

Tags: php, email, attachment

I found a script from codexworld to send an email with an attachment using PHP.  I did edit it slightly as I needed to add a few more inputs, but it works with one exception, it won't send video files.  I will send picture and document files, but no video.  I keep getting the status message:  "Your contact request submission failed, please try again."

Can anyone look at this code and tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

```
    <?php
$postData = $uploadedFile = $statusMsg = '';
$msgClass = 'errordiv';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $postData = $_POST;
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $location=$_POST['location'];
    $URL = $_POST['URL'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $hauntname = $_POST['hauntname'];

// Check whether submitted data is not empty
if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($message)){

    // Validate email
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $statusMsg = 'Please enter your valid email.';
    }else{
        $uploadStatus = 1;

        // Upload attachment file
        if(!empty($_FILES["attachment"]["name"])){

            // File path config
            $targetDir = "uploads/";
            $fileName = basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
            $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
            $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

             // Allow certain file formats
            $allowTypes = array('m4p', 'mp4', 'jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'mov');
            if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
                // Upload file to the server
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                    $uploadedFile = $targetFilePath;
                }else{
                    $uploadStatus = 0;
                    $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.\r\n";
                }
            }else{
                $uploadStatus = 0;
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, only image or video files are allowed to be uploaded.\r\n";
            }

         }

        if($uploadStatus == 1){

            // Recipient
            $toEmail = 'submission@hyhpawardshow.com';

            // Sender
            $from = $email;
            $fromName = $name;

            // Subject
            $emailSubject = $category.' submission from '.$name;

            // Message 
            $htmlContent = '<h2>Submission</h2>
                <p><b>Name:</b> '.$name.'</p>
                <p><b>Haunt Name:</b> '.$hauntname.'</p>
                <p><b>Location:</b> '.$location.'</p>
                <p><b>Email:</b> '.$email.'</p>
                <p><b>Category:</b> '.$category.'</p>
                <p><b>URL:</b> '.$URL.'</p>
                <p><b>Message:</b><br/>'.$message.'</p>';

            // Header for sender info
            $headers = "From: $fromName"." <".$from.">";

            if(!empty($uploadedFile) && file_exists($uploadedFile)){

                // Boundary 
                $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
                $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

                // Headers for attachment 
                $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

                // Multipart boundary 
                $message = "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $htmlContent . "\n\n"; 

                // Preparing attachment
                if(is_file($uploadedFile)){
                    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
                    $fp =    @fopen($uploadedFile,"rb");
                    $data =  @fread($fp,filesize($uploadedFile));
                    @fclose($fp);
                    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
                    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"\n" . 
                    "Content-Description: ".basename($uploadedFile)."\n" .
                    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($uploadedFile)."\"; size=".filesize($uploadedFile).";\n" . 
                    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
                }

                $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--";
                $returnpath = "-f" . $email;

                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $message, $headers, $returnpath);

                // Delete attachment file from the server
                @unlink($uploadedFile);
            }else{
                 // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
                $headers .= "\r\n". "MIME-Version: 1.0";
                $headers .= "\r\n". "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8";

                // Send email
                $mail = mail($toEmail, $emailSubject, $htmlContent, $headers); 
            }

            // If mail sent
            if($mail){
                $statusMsg = "Your contact request has been submitted successfully !\r\n";
                $msgClass = 'succdiv';

                $postData = '';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Your contact request submission failed, please try again.\r\n";
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please fill all the fields.';
}
}

    ?>
```

Comment: Is your mail server configured and do you use the correct credentials?

Comment: Yes, I confirmed them with my hosting provider a few hours ago.

Comment: print out `error_get_last()['message']` if `$mail` is false to get additional error information

Comment: Yeah, I've got to figure out how to do that.  LOL

Answer (score 1):

So, as it turns out, it was not my code at all, but the mail server.  The max file size is messed up and that is what was causing it to fail.  I'm currently working with my hosting tech support to have this resolved.

Thank you all to tried to help.  I truly appreciate it.